# How to send and get JSON data from Node.js into HTML using Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, ajax

I am currently trying to build simple online forum where people can post comments; however, I am not sure how I write is correct way to do. Is Ajax automatically called after the form is submitted by choosing type="POST"?

I am also not sure if I am writing correct programs in routes file.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
// $(function(){
//     $("#target").submit(function(event){
//         event.preventDefault();
//         $.post("/users", function(data){
//             $( "#result" ).html( JSON.stringify(data) );
//         });
//     });
// });
//Not sure which way I should use ↑↓

$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'http://localhost3000/users',
 data: data,
 dataType: 'json'
})

.done(function(data){
  console.log("GET Succeeded");
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify); //What should I put after JSON.stringify?
});

 $(function(){
     $("#target").submit(function(event){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost3000/users',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json'
      })

      .done(function(data){
        console.log("POST Succeeded");
        $('#result').html(JSON.stringify); //What should I put after JSON.stringify?
      });
    });
 });



</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>

<form action="/users" method="post" id="target">
  Username:<input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my routes file

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Users = require('../models/users');

var userRouter = express.Router();
userRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

userRouter.route('/')

.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
        Users.find({}).then(function(user){
          res.json(user)
        }).catch(next);
})

.post(function(req, res, next){
//  res.send("Confirmed");
  Users.create(req.body).then(function(user){
    res.send(user);
  }).catch(next);

  res.json(newUser);
});

module.exports = userRouter;
```

Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = 'my database';
mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});


var routes = require('./router/index');
var userRouter = require('./router/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/users', userRouter);
//Error handler for user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.status(422).send({error: err.message});
});

//catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
if (app.get('env') === 'development'){
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
  });

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
 });

module.exports = app;
```

Thank you：）

Comment: are you referring to the moment the user presses `enter` when the form is in focus or clicks the submit button?

Comment: I'm trying to build the forum which all comments posted are already above the comment form, and when users click the submit button, that comment should also be posted under all comments already posted by others.

Comment: Oh. when submit button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ajax post is not automatically called upon form submission. However, this being said, the browser does send a `post` to the specified endpoint in your form tag.

If you need to automatically display the comments as the posts are made, then you could use the commented block of code in your script.

Another approach would be to do the following....

```
$(function(){
    $("#target").submit(function(event){
        // add code here to append the form data to the DOM

        // dont call event.preventDefault()

        // doing so will take advantage of the browser's 
        // post functionality while giving you a chance
        // to handle the form data locally prior to the post

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest the `postman` chrome plugin,it is a restful api client,you first call the api through it,and then if the api performs perfect,you can write the ajax post else.

Comment: and if you write the ajax post,dont forget to make node server sent the response with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header,because cross domain is not allow in js